# How to allow a sexp within a quoted list to be evaluated?

Tags: quote

```
(setq a 2)
(setq l '(a b c))
(car l)
```

Got `a` when evaluating this, and why its value not `2` ?

Comment: I didn't think this was completely a duplicate at first. But since OP wants to evaluate a variable that's in the list being quoted, it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The single quote inhibits evaluation of elements in the list.  An alternative form would be to use the function `list` instead of single quote, or use a backtick and comma combination.  See:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html

```lisp
(progn
  (setq a 2)
  (setq l `(,a b c))
  (car l))
```

or

```lisp
(let (a b c l)
  (setq a 2)
  (setq l (list a b c))
  (car l))
```